# Upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to version 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, proxy, lts, 22.04

The following command was used to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to version 22.04:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt install update-manager-core && sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

Comment: Maybe try entering each one of those commands individually so you know which one for sure failed.  Although from the sound of the message it was probably the last one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I update my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345217/why-cant-i-update-my-ubuntu-from-18-04-to-20-04)

Comment: Have you tried following these steps? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-22-04-lts/

Answer (score 3):

Use the commands individually:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

I had issues when downloading packages using a nearby server so try it with the main server.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I enter the commands separately, upgrad process does not run, and the following error is observed when entering the *sudo do-release-upgrade -d* command:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release

Comment: did you set the servers for main server instead of nearby

Comment: yes I set to main server

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 behind a proxy server like *apt-cacher* or *apt-cacher-ng* (or behind a corporate firewall), and also for an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

I could fix this problem as follows:

As the error message states, the OS-upgrader *do-release-upgrade* cannot receive the file *meta-release-development* through https:

> Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

The solution is to use *http* instead of *https* for the transmission via proxy. This can be configured by tiny changes in the config file */etc/update-manager/meta-release*:

```
sudo editor /etc/update-manager/meta-release
     # replace every "https" with "http"
sudo apt update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

This message can occur if your proxy server (eg: apt-cacher-ng) doesn't support HTTPS - to work around this add changelogs.ubuntu.com to the PassThroughPattern directive in its configuration file and restart.

Comment: Could you be more explicit so that everyone  understands this:`add changelogs.ubuntu.com to the PassThroughPattern directive in its configuration file` ?